# react webview white screen after splash screen

Tags: react-native

I want to get rid of the white screen

app.js
import React, { useRef, useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import { BackHandler, Platform, StyleSheet,ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";

```
export default function App() {
  const webView = useRef();

  const [canGoBack, setCanGoBack] = useState(false);
  const handleBack = useCallback(() => {
    if (canGoBack && webView.current) {
      webView.current.goBack();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }, [canGoBack]);

  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handleBack);
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", handleBack);
    };
  }, [handleBack]);
const App = () => (
  <View style={[styles.container, styles.horizontal]}>
    <ActivityIndicator />
    <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
    <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#0000ff" />
    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#00ff00" />
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  horizontal: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    padding: 10,
  },
});


  const platformStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    webView: Platform.OS === 'ios' 
      ? { marginTop: 30, marginBottom: 40 }
      : { marginTop: 30 }
  });


  return (
    <WebView
      ref={webView}
      source={{ uri: "https://www.talesrunnerbestguild.co.kr/" }}
     
      style = {platformStyles.webView}
      onLoadProgress={(event) => setCanGoBack(event.nativeEvent.canGoBack)}
    />
  );

}
```

Comment: Seems there are some unnecessary parts in your code, please clean them up or clarify further. (Are the "App" and "styles" in the middle part of the code relevant to your question?). I also advise you to provide screenshots as well so that others can understand the question better. (Can you show us the white screen you are referring to?)

Answer (score 0):

In your `<WebView>`, you are passing `platformStyles.webView` which only has `marginTop` and `marginBottom` defined.

The white screen may not be a component shown on your app. Rather I believe it could be that there are no components being shown in your initial code, so you only see a white screen.

To check if this is the case, you can wrap your `<WebView>` with a `<View>` element with a red (or whatever color you prefer) background color.

For example,

```
<View style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
  <WebView
    ref={webView}
    source={{ uri: "https://www.talesrunnerbestguild.co.kr/" }}
     
    style = {platformStyles.webView}
    onLoadProgress={(event) => setCanGoBack(event.nativeEvent.canGoBack)}
  />
</View>
```

If so, you can try fixing the `platformStyles.webView` style by filling the entire screen with `flex: 1`.

```
const platformStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    webView: Platform.OS === 'ios' 
      ? { marginTop: 30, marginBottom: 40, flex: 1 }
      : { marginTop: 30, flex: 1 }
  });
```